# Using variable instead of symbol in update_attribute

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I'm pretty new to all this, so please assume the worst about my knowledge. Regarding

```
record = tablename.new
result["top"].each do |r|    #result is the answer from a variable length JSON
  if ActiveRecord::Base.connection.column_exists?(:tablename, r["aaa"]["bbb"] )
    record.update_attribute(r["aaa"]["bbb"] , r["ccc"] )
  else
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.add_column(:tablename, r["aaa"]["bbb"] , :integer )
    #record.update_attribute( r["aaa"]["bbb"] , r["ccc"] )
  end
record.save
```

I get this error since I'm using a variable instead of a symbol in update_attribute:

```
undefined method `stringify_keys' for "contents of r["aaa"]["bbb"]":String (NoMethodError)
```

I can't use a symbol though, since I don't actually know the column's name - it's all dynamically generated, as you can see from this line:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.add_column(:tablename, r["aaa"]["bbb"] , :integer )
```

In short, how can I accommodate for having a variable column name with update_attribute?

Comment: there's no `stringify_keys` method on String. Nor on Symbol, for that matter.

Comment: Um, I don't know what a stack trace is, but the full error is: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.3/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:69:in `assign_attributes': undefined method `stringify_keys' for "contents of r["aaa"]["bbb"]":String (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your string to a symbol using [String#to_sym](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-to_sym)

```
record.update_attribute(r["aaa"]["bbb"].to_sym , r["ccc"] )
```

Comment: Good suggestion, but that gets me this error, timestamp being a previously established column in the DB: active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing': undefined method `contents of r["aaa"]["bbb"] and then for some reason an equals sign =' for #tablename id: nil, timestamp: "2012-10-28 13:01:47"> (NoMethodError)

Comment: `record.update_attribute(:foo, "something")` effectively does `record.foo = "something"; record.save`, so you need a `foo` column in your database in order to save it. Do you have a column in your table for whatever `r["aaa"]["bbb"]` returns?

Comment: Yes, the add_column inserts the column names r["aaa"]["bbb"] if they don't exist, as expected.

Comment: You should call `tablename.reset_column_information` after creating the column to refresh the ActiveRecord cache for your model.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but not enough points to comment.

edouardbriere answered your question but can you please explain your use case? Editing the schema as a result of some data is almost never anywhere near the correct way to do something.